# How to convert an IO String to a algebraic Type of data "Products" of a txt file?

Tags: haskell, io

I have to ask the user to enter the code, the name, and the price of a product in Products.txt.

```
produtoPath::FilePath
produtoPath = "Products.txt"

 adicionaProd::IO()
 adicionaProd = do
    putStr "Product's Code:"
    cod<-getLine
    putStr "Product's Name:"
    nom<-getLine
    putStr "Product's Price:"
    pre<-getLine
--  appendFile produtoPath
    putStr "Do you want to add some other product?"
    resp <- getLine
    if ((resp == "y")) then adicionaProd else return()
```

So, after the products have been added, I have to create another function that will read the contents of Products.txt, and return Products ... type Products = [(Code, Name, Price)], and I do not know how to do this ...
I've tried, but I could not.

```
 generateList:: [[String]]-> Produtos
 generateList [] = []
 --generateList [[cod,nom,pre]:[]] = [(read:cod)::]
```

After that, I have to load the products with the function loadProducts ... That reads the files of the previous function, and returns the type IO Products, in order that the user can visualize what is in the file in the format of the type Products .

```
loadTable:: IO Produtos
loadTable = do
         s<-readFile produtoPath
    --   return generateList (map words)
```

In summary: I do not know the way I should be saving the data in the "addProd" function, to read the file and generate Products cpm the generateList function, and load them to the user with the loadTable function.Can you help me?
Complete code of what I did: https://ideone.com/Al9ZLf

Comment: try using `show :: Show a => a -> String` to convert from `[(Code, Name, Price)]` to `String` and `read :: Read a => String -> a` to convert from `String` to `[(Code, Name, Price)]`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to *return* the input data from `adicionaProd`. So, its type must become

```
type Products   = [(Code, Name, Price)]
adicionaProd :: IO Products
```

Then, you adjust the code itself

```
 adicionaProd = do
    putStr "Product's Code:"
    cod<-getLine
    putStr "Product's Name:"
    nom<-getLine
    putStr "Product's Price:"
    pre<-getLine
    let prod :: (Code, Name, Price)
        prod = (read cod, nom, read pre)
    putStr "Do you want to add some other product?"
    resp <- getLine
    if resp == "y" then do
       rest <- adicionaProd 
       return (prod : rest)
    else 
       return [prod]
```

The idea is: if the response is "yes", then you recursively ask for a list of products, and bind it to `rest`. Then, you return a list comprising your product and following with the rest. If the response is "no", you return a list containing the first product, only.